# Column A value based on groupby aggregation of Column B

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe with donation information, example below:

```
DonorID  DonationID     Date        Amount
a1234    3767           1/1/2019    $100
a1234    2193           2/1/2019    $50
a1234    0915           3/1/2019    $75
b5678    4562           5/1/2019    $45
b5678    8965           4/1/2019    $80
```

I'm using the groupby function to calculate the total per DonorID and min date but would also like to calculate the amount of the earliest donation and DonationID by DonorID.

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['DonorID'], as_index=False ).agg( {'Amount':sum,'Date':min})
```

Current output is:

```
DonorID      Amount         Date
a1234        $225           1/1/2019
b5678        $125           4/1/2019
```

The desired output would be along the lines of:

```
DonorID      Amount          Date               First Gift Amount      DonationID
a1234        $225            1/1/2019           $100                   3767
b5678        $125            4/1/2019           $80                    8965
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You might want something like this:

```
df.sort_values('Date').groupby(['DonorID'], as_index=False)\
  .agg({'Amount':['sum', 'first'], 'Date': 'min', 'DonationID': 'first'})
```

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 ways you can approach this.

1. You can first sort your dataframe on the `"date"` column. This will ensure that when you use the aggregation method `"first"` that you will get whichever value that corresponds with the minimum date.

```
df2 = (df1
       .sort_values("Date")
       .groupby(["DonorID"], as_index=False)
       .agg(
           amount=("Amount", "sum"),
           date=("Date", "min"),
           first_amount=("Amount", "first"),
           donation_id=("DonationID", "first"))
      )

print(df2)
  DonorID  amount       date  first_amount  donation_id
0   a1234     225 2019-01-01           100         3767
1   b5678     125 2019-04-01            80         8965
```

2. If you don't want to use `sort_values` (for whatever reason). You can assign a temporary column to get the `idxmin()` of your `"Date"` column. Then you can use `map` to extract the related values from your original dataframe:

```
df2 = (df1
       .groupby(["DonorID"], as_index=False)
       .agg(
           amount=("Amount", "sum"),
           date=("Date", "min"),
           min_date_idx=("Date", "idxmin"))
       .assign(
           first_amount=lambda d: d["min_date_idx"].map(df1["Amount"]),
           donation_id=lambda d: d["min_date_idx"].map(df1["DonationID"])
       ))

print(df2)

  DonorID  amount       date  min_date_idx  first_amount  donation_id
0   a1234     225 2019-01-01             0           100         3767
1   b5678     125 2019-04-01             4            80         8965
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using the `agg()` method and unpacking a dictionary. This allows you to have column names with spaces in them.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].str.replace('$','')
df['Amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Amount'])
df.sort_values(by='Date',ascending=True).groupby('DonorID').agg(**{'Amount': ('Amount','sum'),'Date':('Date','first'),'First Gift Amount': ('Amount','first'),'DonationID':('DonationID','first')})
```